# Why does x2go server start another ssh-agent when I start up x2go client?

Tags: x2go

I have x2go server on my Ubuntu machine. When I start x2goclient on my Windows machine to bring up the Ubuntu graphical desktop, I see that a second ssh-agent process is started on the Ubuntu machine, even though there was already an ssh-agent process running (and it contained a key).

Why is this second ssh-agent process started, and is there any way I can prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

x2goserver "makes" a ssh tunnel forwarding.
In the script /usr/bin/x2gostartagent

```
 X2GO_PORT='7474'# per default it is port 50, but if you have more than one
                # x2goserver running, give every server a different port range
                # otherwise every time you open an session, the previous session
                # will disappear
```